# Renaming mutliple files in one shot - what's wrong with that command?

Tags: sed, find, rename, mv, echo

I have multiple files in a directory:

```
$ ls -1
04PD.001
04PD.002
04PD.003
04PD.004
04PD.005
```

Now I'd like to change the name of each file to something like `04PD.7z.0*`

Can someone tell me what's wrong with that command:

```
$ find 04PD* -type f -print -exec mv \{\} `echo \{\} | sed "s/04PD\.0/04PD\.7z\.0/"` \;
```

The result is utmost strange:

```
$ find 04PD* -type f -print -exec mv \{\} `echo \{\} | sed "s/04PD\.0/04PD\.7z\.0/"` \;
04PD.001
mv: '04PD.001' and '04PD.001' are the same file
04PD.002
mv: '04PD.002' and '04PD.002' are the same file
04PD.003
mv: '04PD.003' and '04PD.003' are the same file
04PD.004
mv: '04PD.004' and '04PD.004' are the same file
04PD.005
mv: '04PD.005' and '04PD.005' are the same file
```

To test the command I changed the command to simple echo:

```
$ find Pop*04PD* -type f -print -exec echo mv \{\} `echo \{\} | sed "s/04PD\.0/04PD\.7z\.0/"` \;
04PD.001
mv 04PD.001 04PD.001
04PD.002
mv 04PD.002 04PD.002
04PD.003
mv 04PD.003 04PD.003
04PD.004
mv 04PD.004 04PD.004
04PD.005
mv 04PD.005 04PD.005
```

Note: I've already found a very nice & simple solution with a loop, so please focus on what's wrong with this command, rather that proposing another solution.

I am pretty curious where the error is.

Comment: Change the `mv` command to `echo mv` and see what you get

Comment: Oh @roaima , you're spoiling all the fun for the others. Of course I did.

Comment: Sensei @muru , thanks. Perhaps I shall add an Q&A answer based on the linked questions? Would you please reopen the question...

Comment: @Pawel your question is answered by the “Pipelined Sed ...” question, it doesn’t seem particularly useful to add another variant of that as an answer here.

Comment: Hmm, actually I deemed that it would be worthwhile to explain what makes the problem in my case and how to circumvent it, but you have far more experience so perhaps you're right.